# Owl Carousel autoWidth Broken on Initial & Cache Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel, page-refresh

I am finding randomly (and VERY often) that with autoWidth turned on for my "Looping Photostrip" Owl Carousels, when I first go a page containing one (tested from multiple devices), the slides are not there. If I Refresh, they appear. Any time I Cache Refresh, they disappear again. Something is not right, but my code looks just fine.

```
$('.photo-strip.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  autoWidth:true,
  autoplayTimeout:2500,
  autoplaySpeed:1000,
  autoplay:true,
  autoplayHoverPause:true,
  items:10
});
```

This is happening on multiple sites that I use the Carousel on. Please see the attached images as reference. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you!

Site References:

http://911dj.smallmind.co/about-us/

http://911dj.smallmind.co/sweet-16-dj/

http://www.palermopr.com/

[image]

Comment: Wrap your code in the `$(document).ready(function() {//here });` incase your script is executing before the HTML is there.

Comment: Thank you - though it should be `$(window).load(function()` instead of `$(document).ready(function()`. `$(window).load(function()` allows for the images to load before the jQuery.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @Jon correction - the above load function is deprecated and is now `$(window).on('load',function()` in jQuery 3+.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that, I'll use it from now on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resolved this by using:

```
$(window).on('load',function()
```

Initially I was using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
```

$(window).load(function() allows the images to load first before the jQuery loads. That was the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I couldn't find any solution!
But I fixed it by `style` to images.
The solution is :

```
img {
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
}
```

This image related to your carousel image. I hope it can help you as well